# Как сделать прозрачным навбар (бутстрап)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BV</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<img src="https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/2/7b/nissan-gt-r-by-liberty-walk-nissan-gt-r-by-liberty-walk-niss.jpg">
```

Comment: через rgba не выходит

Comment: Прямо сейчас в том коде, который вы показали, каждый элемент (кроме кнопки) абсолютно прозрачный. В чём проблема?

Comment: Неожиданно, тогда не понимаю как навбар расположить над картинкой которая идёт после навбара

Comment: Нужно чтобы навбар(бутстрап) был размещён на картинке, при этом чтобы он был прозрачный, и от него было видно только лого, home и link
Это решение навбара из коробки, здесь нет стилей css

Comment: @andreymal в том что стили бутстрапа не подключены, там `navbar-light` с фоном

Comment: не копируйте вслепую классы в разметке. попробуйте хотя бы разобраться. Очевидно, как минимум `.bg-light` дает вам заливку фона. Но есть еще и `,navbar-light` которому также надо перекрыть фон.

Comment: `<nav style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">...</nav>`

Comment: вам картинка то на фон страницы нужна?

Comment: @teran значит автору нужно подключить бутстрап нужной версии в этом сниппете